# What is the difference between 「利{り}益{えき}」 and 「利{り}潤{じゅん}」?

Tags: meaning, usage

What is the difference between 「利益」 and 「利潤」? They both mean "profit". When shoud I use each of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per my knowledge, 利潤 is used as Profit in economical terms. Where as, 利益 can be used as gains/returns in terms of advantage. For example:

```
利潤：もちろん、利潤は生産費を上回るべきです。
          Benefits of course should exceed the costs.

利益：利益になるような本を読みなさい。
          Read the kind of books that teach you something.
```

As you can see, 利益 is usually used in terms of benefit or advantages. But 利潤 is almost always used for monetary profits. I am saying almost, because I am not a native myself.

Comment: 利益 often refers to monetary profits as well.